# Different behaviour of Grails association

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We've encountered a very strange problem with using Grails association mapping using the `hasMany` relationship. We're using Grails 2.4.4 with hibernate 3.6.10.18.

We have below three domain structure:

**Person.groovy**

```
package com.org

Person {

    String email
    Set<Favorite> favorites
    List<Activity> activities

    static hasMany = [favorites: Favorite, activities: Activity]
}
```

**Favorite.groovy**

```
package com.org

Favorite {

    String name

    static hasMany = [persons: Person]
    static belongsTo = Person
}
```

**Activity.groovy**

```
package com.org

Activity {
    String title
    List<Favorite> favorites = []

    static hasMany = [favorites: Favorite]
    static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}
```

This domain structure was working fine on production server for many years and suddenly it starts throwing some exception when we use the following code:

```
Person personInstance = Parson.first()  // Valid saved person instance
Activity acitivityInstnace = new Activity([title: "example"])
activityInstance.addToFavorites(Favorite.get(1))   // Both instance already exists
activityInstance.addToFavorites(Favorite.get(2))
activityInstance.setPerson(personInstance)
activityInstance.save()
println activityInstance.id
```

The exception being thrown was (where id is being printed):

```
2015-04-01 12:02:40,886 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: collection [com.org.Favorite.persons] was not processed by flush()
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:102)
    at com.org.ActivityService.save(ActivityService.groovy:50)
    at com.org.ActivityController.save(ActivityController.groovy:137)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I tried to dig into the code of `GormStaticApi` and followed some code and found out that the `Favorite` domain class has an invalid mapping of `hasMany` and `belongsTo` reference. As we removed that mapping from `Favorite` domain class, the exception don't occur.

Why was this code running before and why aren't we able to reproduce this in the local environment? Before last deployment, nothing is changed.

Comment: Is this the actual code which you have pasted above? Are you really doing Favorite.get(1) and Favorite.get(2) in your code ? or its dynamic? What is the line 50 in ActivityService

Comment: It is actually dynamic, the IDs used to come from the client side but all IDs exists in the system for sure.

Comment: In your Activity domain, you have  static belongsTo = Person - so you dont have a property of type Person, I wonder how can you do activityInstance.setPerson(personInstance) - there's no such property

Comment: You should paste the actual code the root of the problem could be somewhere in there

Comment: Sorry @sudhir, my fault. I've updated the code of `Activity` domain class.

Comment: I am more interested in looking at the real code inside ActivityService.save and also line no 50

Comment: Thank you for replying @sudhir. I've already posted the required snippet from the original code. As I've already mentioned, the line 50 where the exception is being thrown, is where I'm printing the id after `save()` call. Other than this, the save method of the service only contains the data binding code.